# Array output midification with comparing

Tags: java, arrays

Output has to be an array of 20 with 10 numbers in each line.If the input(K) is 0 then the array numbers will be a random between -10 and 20 , if not A[0] is 0.5 and you calculate the other ones with this : A[i] = A[i-1]*K/3.So,after that it has check to the numbers and after the first one which is bigger than 10 it has to add a zero,moving the numbers after that, by one position and removing the last one,so it still outputs 20 numbers.How can i insert a zero?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;


public class Ld3151rdb258 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double A[] = new double[20];
    int K, i;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Andris Osītis IRDBD03 151RDB258");  
    System.out.print("K=");
    try {
        K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        return;
    }

    if (K==0) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (i=1; i<20; i++)
            A[i] = r.nextDouble()*30-10;
    }
    else
        for (i=0; i<20; i++)
                A[0] = 0.5;
        for (i=1; i<20;i++ )
                A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d ;

    System.out.println("A:");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.1d\t", A[i]);
        if (i==9) System.out.println();
    }


    System.out.println("\nA:");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.1d\t", A[i]);
        if (i==9) System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can i insert a zero after the first nunber that is bigger than 10 in the ouput?

Answer (score 0):

try using curly braces around your block of code

```
else {
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
            A[0] = 0.5;
    for (i=1; i<20;i++ )
            A[i] = i-1*K/3.0d ;
}
```

But I also think you want to increment your A array????

Comment: yes, i have  to add code where it compares the A elements to 10 and after the first one adds a zero(moving the following elements by one place deleting the last one,still has to output an array of 20),dunno how to write that.